# "絶対について来ないでね。" as "Absolutely don't come/follow"

Tags: translation, spelling

Overheard the phrase which sounded like "絶対について来ないでね。". I believe it means 'absolutely don't come/follow'. The speaker was actually hinting to follow her. I'm just curious if my translation makes sense, and if I've spelled things correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your translation is absolutely correct and 絶対について来ないでね literally means "Never follow me".

But in some situations, 絶対にXするなよ can be taken as a hint of "Do X (at your own risk)"! If native speakers encounter a girl who says 絶対について来ないでね in manga or light-novels, they can instantly imagine the テンプレ ("template") story after this: the boy who heard this would end up in following her.

The key word here is **絶対に** which is described [here](http://dic.nicovideo.jp/a/%E7%B5%B6%E5%AF%BE%E3%81%AB%E6%8A%BC%E3%81%99%E3%81%AA%E3%82%88). 「[絶対に押すなよ](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J0FCgvLxeiM)」 is a famous joke by a comedian group called [ダチョウ倶楽部](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%80%E3%83%81%E3%83%A7%E3%82%A6%E5%80%B6%E6%A5%BD%E9%83%A8), and they often used 絶対にするな somehow as a sign of "Do it".

Japanese people who know this background often make pages titled [絶対に見るなよ!](https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=%E7%B5%B6%E5%AF%BE%E3%81%AB%E8%A6%8B%E3%82%8B%E3%81%AA%E3%82%88), which are actually intended to be seen by many.

If a real woman says 絶対について来ないでね, you'll have to determine whether she is saying it seriously or jokingly. It can be extremely difficult even for native speakers to tell what she is actually thinking.

Comment: Watch this [typical(?) usage of 絶対に](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xcD6lThYjFg) from a Japanese game. The girl is an *owarai* fan who is obviously expecting a birthday preset from the player.

Comment: Really awesome explanation.This clears it up really well. However, sometimes 絶対 is used to mean exactly what you'd think too. これも絶対にやめてほしい行為。actually means 'I want this to stop immediately' If I'm correct.