# Need help about the meaning of a character's thought about his cousin （今の流れは、そういう“振り”だと思うじゃん）

Tags: meaning, reading-comprehension, japanese-to-english, video-games, conversations

[image]

**（今の流れは、そういう“振り”だと思うじゃん）**

**Hope someone can explains Mc's thought correctly about his cousin here (My guess but not sure : "You know I'm about to punch you , so you're pretending to avoid that aren't you ?" )**

Context: MC is talking with his little cousin and her friend/classmate. Kotori is Mc's cousin , and she tends to talking too much (like being noisy at Mc's house), so MC often punch her to make his cousin shut up (LOL what a big brother). So Kotori is really scared when MC gets annoyed by what she said behind his back, after her classmate talked with him.

MC「俺は森野賢人。よろしくね」

Chiwa (Cousin's friend/classmate)「はい。こちらこそよろしくお願いします！」

「あとお兄さんのことは、小鳥ちゃんからよく聞いてますよ」

MC「小鳥から？」

Chiwa「わッ！？で、でも聞いてるって言っても、変な話じゃないですよ！！？」​

「毎年従兄弟のお兄さんの家に遊びに行ってて」

「話しかけると面倒くさそうな顔するけど、すごく優しくて大好きなお兄さんだって」

Kotori「なッ！？　ちょ、チワプー！？私そこまで言ってない！！！」

MC「小鳥……お前、そんな風に思ってたの？？？」(Kotori is very scared right now, trembling ^^)

Kotori「おい言ったそばから面倒くさそうな顔すんなッ！！！！」(then she tried to speak tough to MC)

**MC（今の流れは、そういう“振り”だと思うじゃん）**

都会に憧れを持っている小鳥は、毎年夏休みになるとうちに泊まりに来る。

とはいえただ遊びに来ているわけでなく――

小鳥の父さんの兄貴……つまり“うちの父さん”が亡くなってからは、

名目上は『俺と母さんを手伝いに来る』という、大義名分の元に毎年訪ねてきているわけだ。

実際小鳥は放っておいても勝手に喋るので、その数日は喧しいくらい家の中が明るくなる。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This 振り corresponds to this definition on jisho.org:

> #### [振り](https://jisho.org/word/%E6%8C%AF%E3%82%8A)
>
> 6. lead in (e.g. to a running joke, asking a question); lead up​
>    <sub>Usually written using kana alone, See also 前振り, oft. as フリ</sub>

In the context of a comedy or talk show, フリ (also called 前フリ) refers to setting up a situation or context that leads to a main joke. When you notice someone's フリ, you are expected to follow along and respond with an appropriate joke. A classic example of フリ in English would be [*knock-knock*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knock-knock_joke). A classic Japanese example would be [絶対にXするなよ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/29030/5010). Many フリ are more obscure and subjective.

In this context, the two girls said 「話しかけると面倒くさそうな顔するけど、すごく優しくて大好きなお兄さんだ」 and 「なッ！？　ちょ、チワプー！？私そこまで言ってない！！！」, and these are the comments that MC thought were フリ. Following along with this flow, MC said 「小鳥……お前、そんな風に思ってたの」 in a deliberately tedious (or annoyed) tone, thinking it would serve as a joke.

However, Kotori didn't get MC's joke and seemed genuinely scared. So he said this in mind:

> 今の流れは、そういう“振り”だと思うじゃん
> I thought the current flow was like that kind of *lead in*, wasn't it?

Comment: ohh...I got it.  MC thought Kotori had given him a cue, so he responded with an annoyed expression. However, this hurt Kotori because she secretly thought that MC was kind and sweet.  That's why she said don't make that annoyed face.